# Loop through a list and combine totals where an identifier is the same

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I cuurently have a list of objetcs Cars
The variables within are:

> Make
>
> Model
>
> Service Cost

Lets say I have the list filled up with:

> Ferrari, F50, 300
>
> Porsche, 911, 700
>
> Toyota, Camary, 300
>
> Porsche, 911, 400
>
> BMW, Z4, 1200
>
> Porsche, 911, 900
>
> Porsche, 356A, 700

As you can see, my list contains three records where the Porsche 911 has service costs.

How would I loop through my list, find the duplicate 911's and combine them to form one single record? So that I end up with:

> Ferrari, F50, 300
>
> Porsche, 911, 2000
>
> Toyota, Camary, 300
>
> BMW, Z4, 1200
>
> Porsche, 356A, 700

What I've done so far is not going to work, as my records would propbably end up in the wrong areas:

```
    List<Car> CombinedCarRecords = new List<Car>(CarDetailRecords); //Original list here being used
    List<Car> NormalList = new List<Car>();
    List<Car> NewList = new List<Car>();//Making new lists to keep the records in
    Car normalRecord = new Car();
    Car combinedRecord = new Car();//new objects to keep the values in and add the others
    string oldVal = "";
    string newVal = "";//used to find the same cars
    foreach (var item in CombinedCarRecords )
    {
        normalRecord = new ClaimDetailRecord();
        combinedRecord = new ClaimDetailRecord();
        oldVal = newVal;
        newVal = item.Model;
        if (oldVal == newVal)
        {
            combinedRecord = item;
            CombinedCarRecords.Add(combinedRecord);
        }
        else
        {
            normalRecord = item;
            NormalList.Add(normalRecord);
        }
    }//I think the way I try to find the records here is not working, as the old and new values will always be different, if maybe not for some records where they are right after each other. But there is still that initial one

    decimal totalP = 0;

    if (CombinedTariffsRecords.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in CombinedTariffsRecords)
        {
        }
    }
    else
        NewList = NormalList;
    //This is where I'm supposed to add up the totals, but I think my code before will render this code useless
```

So in all,I have tried, but I cannot come up with a better way to store the values and combine my records.

Comment: Take a look to GroupBy() extension method.

Comment: When looping through your list, you are creating a list of duplicate records, but you don't check that list if an item already exist. It's quite simple: loop through all your items, if not in list, clone object and put in another list (list N) else add the service cost to existing (in list N) row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use LINQ's `Enumerable.GroupBy` and `Sum`:

```
var newCarList = NormalList
   .GroupBy(c => new {  c.Make, c.Model })
   .Select(carGroup => new Car{ 
       Make = carGroup.Key.Make, 
       Model = carGroup.Key.Model,
       ServiceCost = carGroup.Sum(c => c.ServiceCost)
    })
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var cars = new List<Car> 
    { 
        new Car { Make = "Ferrari", Model = "F50", ServiceCost = 1000 },
        new Car { Make = "Ferrari", Model = "F50", ServiceCost = 2000 },
        new Car { Make = "Porsche", Model = "911", ServiceCost = 2000 }
    };
    var grouped = cars.GroupBy(car => car.Make + car.Model).Select(g => new { g.Key, Costs = g.Sum(e => e.ServiceCost), Element = g.First() });
    foreach (var g in grouped)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}: {2}", g.Element.Make, g.Element.Model, g.Costs);
    }
}

class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }

    public decimal ServiceCost { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Adding two values to generate a key can lead to conflicts *and* generates one more temporary string